# Making template class get another class as <T> and consider it as data type (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

I suppose to do some unusual stuff. I have a class template:

```
template<class T> class CFile
```

I want to build another class which would have a member of int type,

```
class foo
{
private:
     int memb;
}
```

when I pass the "foo" class as "< T >" to "CFile", `foo` is supposed to simply act as integer. I need ideas how to implement it only with internal logic in `foo`, without changing `CFile` (CFile is not allowed to contain any logic which extracts the int member from the class).

It's for a task in college, so I should not change the rules given to me. It should look like this:

```
class foo
{
    int memb;
}

int main()
{
  foo myFoo;

  // The ctor of CFile takes a file path and opens the file. After that it can write 
  // members from type < T > to the file. I need the CFile to write the memb member to
  // the file (Remember that the CFile is passed as < T >

  CFile<foo> file("c:\\file.txt");

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "consider the whole class as the "memb" int member."

Comment: You should state the problem that you are trying to solve, rather than the problem you are finding with your approach. Including, if relevant, what is `CFile`, and why you cannot modify it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to add `operator const int() {return memb;}` to `foo`?

Comment: what is operator const int() does?

Comment: @user783294: If I understand correctly: When instantiating the template `some_template<typename _Parameter>`, you want the compiler to analyze the type passed as `_Parameter`, look for a member called `a_member` and retrieve its type for later use in the compiling process. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're trying to do is for `class foo` to act as an integer. For this effect you need to provide:

- A constructor that can create a `foo` from an `int`.
- An overloaded cast operator that implicitly casts your `foo` class to an `int`.

You would have something like this:

```
class foo {
public:
  foo() {} // Create a foo without initializing it
  foo(const int &memb): _memb(memb) {} // Create and initialize a foo

  operator int&() {return _memb;} // If foo is not constant
  operator const int&() const {return _memb;} // If foo is constant

private:
  int _memb;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If CFile uses streams to write to the file then you only need to implement operator<< in the Foo class.

Something like:

```
ofstream file;

file.open("file.txt"); //open a file

file<<T; //write to it

file.close(); //close it
```

in the CFile and this added to Foo:

```
ofstream &operator<<(ofstream &stream, Foo& foo)
{
  stream << foo.memb;

  return stream; 
}
```